# opacity fade on multiple divs at once, all with different opacity values.

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make it so 10 squares fade in all at once with different opacity values for each square.
So far I have all 10 squares fading in at once, but all have the same opacity value `1`.
I'm not sure of the best way to achieve the next step, and I need to do so with core JavaScript (no library's of any kind).

This is what I have so far:

```
var color;
var count = 0;

function init() {
    color = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    setInterval(fadeColor, 1000);
}

function fadeColor() {
    setInterval(fade, 50);
}

function fade() {
    for(i=0; i < color.length; i++){
        color[i].style.opacity = count;
    }

    count = count + 0.01;
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

Comment: `i` is leaking, try `for(var i=0,...)`

Comment: why do you need two time intervals where one is starting another?

Comment: Are you looking to give them a random opacity or have some type of geometric relationship?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `color[i].style.opacity = count` you can try something like this

```
var opacity = color[i].style.opacity;
if (opacity < opacity_levels[i]) {
    color[i].style.opacity = opacity + 0.01;
}
```

where`opacity_levels` is an array of desired opacity levels for each element.

Comment: Not sure if I did something wrong but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that generates ten boxes and then fades them in to random levels of opacity. The basis of this method is storing opacity end points as properties of each box object. The program loops across the ten boxes checking to see if the end point has been reached. When it is, the program skips this box for all further changes to opacity. When all ten boxes have reached their end points the program stops.

You can run it all again by clicking the run again button.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Opacity fade</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var totDivs=new Array(), allDivs=new Array(); // global
 function init()
  { // gather divs
      totDivs=document.getElementById("wrap").getElementsByTagName("div");
      var i, endP;
     // discard outer div from collection 
      for(i=0;i<totDivs.length;i++)
       { if(totDivs[i].className !="ht" && totDivs[i].id !="block2" && totDivs[i].id !="retry" )
           { allDivs[allDivs.length]=totDivs[i]; }                 
       }    
     //   
      var thisCode, newNode, elemD;
      for(i=0;i<allDivs.length;i++) 
       {   allDivs[i].end=Math.random();
           allDivs[i].style.opacity= allDivs[i].currentOpacity =0.1;           
           allDivs[i].skip=false;
           endP=parseInt(allDivs[i].end*100)/100;          
          // add opacity figure into existing div     
           newNode=document.createTextNode(endP);  
           var elemD=document.createElement("div"); 
           elemD.appendChild(newNode);                
           allDivs[i].parentNode.appendChild(elemD);                    
       } 
   //    
    setTimeout(fadeIn,500);     
  } 
 // -----
  function fadeIn()
   { var i, thisStep, counter=0;
     for(i=0;i<10;i++) 
      { thisStep=allDivs[i].currentOpacity+0.05;
        if(thisStep<allDivs[i].end)
          { allDivs[i].style.opacity = allDivs[i].currentOpacity = thisStep; }         
        else
          { if(allDivs[i].skip==false) { counter++; allDivs[i].skip==true; }                            
           }
      } 
    if(counter<10) { setTimeout(fadeIn,100); }
    else { document.getElementById("block2").innerHTML='<div class="a14B">Finished</div>'; }

  }
//     
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body { font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:normal; font-size:11px; color:#000; text-align:center; margin:3px 0px; }
form { margin-top:50px; }
#wrap { border:1px solid #CCC; position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; width:700px; height:400px; margin:50px; padding:20px;   }
#block2 { z-index:2; border:1px solid #000; width:100%; height:20px; background-color: #FF0; margin:15px -15px; }
.blk  { z-index:5; width:50px; height:50px; border:1px solid #00F; opacity:0; background-color:#000;  }
.ht   { float:left; width:50px; height:65px; margin-right:10px;  }
.a14B { position:absolute; top:0px; right:2px; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#000; }
#a0 { background-color:#AAA; }
#a1 { background-color:#F00; }
#a2 { background-color:#FF0; }
#a3 { background-color:#0F0; }
#a4 { background-color:#0FF; }
#a5 { background-color:#00F; }
#a6 { background-color:#F0F; }
#a7 {  background-color:#666; }
#a8 {  background-color:#000; }
#a9 {  background-color:#000080; }
</style>
</head>

<body onload="init()">

<div id="wrap">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var i, build="";
   for(i=0;i<10;i++) { build+='<div  class="ht">\n<div id="a'+i+'" class="blk"><\/div>\n<\/div>\n'; }
  // write to page
   document.write(build); 
  </script>
  <div id="block2">
  </div>
  <div id="retry">
    <input type="button" onclick="location.reload()" value="Run it again" name="b1"></div>
</div>
<!-- end wrap -->

</body>

</html>
```